# AngularJS model not updating inside javascript array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, element, bind

I have a simple issue with AngularJS: **the properties outside of the array update normally, but the array elements (that are bound to those properties) don't**, here is a plunker to show that: http://plnkr.co/edit/gNtGhiTf228G8rP0O2iB?p=preview

```
var vm = this;

vm.topLine = {
        netWrittenPremiumLastFye: 1000000,
        netWrittenPremiumYtd: 123000
    }

vm.grossColumnChartData = [
        ['Previous YE', vm.topLine.netWrittenPremiumLastFye],
        ['YTD', vm.topLine.netWrittenPremiumYtd]
    ];
```

We can use $scope.$watch('something', function(oldValue, newValue) {...}) but that's not a good choice in my situation since i'll have to do that many times, repeatedly.

I want to take advantage of angular 2-way binding as explained above.

Any helps or suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way you can do this without using $watch is by updating the array directly in the html binding.

```
{{ grossColumnChartData = [
        ['Previous YE', vm.topLine.netWrittenPremiumLastFye],
        ['YTD', vm.topLine.netWrittenPremiumYtd]
    ] }}
<br/>
grossColumnChartData = {{grossColumnChartData | json}}
```

See this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uthXcvoWSV2XNRFJzkck?p=preview

Comment: Oh but i need to model somewhere else in the controller, not just in HTML. Why the array elements with Angular binding don't change? So curious. Anyway thanks for that, at least i have another option :)
Very great if we have somehow to update the array elements in the controller.

Comment: There is another option -- $watch -- but you said you don't want to use it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my plnkr and i have my answer now: http://plnkr.co/edit/gNtGhiTf228G8rP0O2iB?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.grossColumnChartData">
    <label>Input {{$index+1}}:</label>
    <input ng-model="item.data" type="text"/>
</div>
```

I was confused between data binding and reference.

I used ng-repeat to update the array elements.